# formvalidation.io autofocus to hidden target

Tags: javascript, jquery, formvalidation-plugin, formvalidation.io

I have a form that has hidden fields and `display: none` fields that need to be validated. I'm using [formvalidation.io](http://formvalidation.io/) Although the validation setup works, the first invalid field can't be autofocused to (the page stays in place and does not scroll to the invalid element).

This is because, I'm guessing, it uses `animate({ scrolltop: y})` and it cannot scroll to a hidden element.

Is there a way to customize the autofocus target such that I want the form to scroll to the `form-group` instead of the hidden field?

Answer (score 1):

I instead trapped the `err.form.fv` event, got the first offending field, got its form-group (which is visible) and scrolled to that. Like so:

```
$('#formMain').formValidation({
    // your settings here   
})
.on('err.form.fv', function (e) {
    // get the INVALID'ed field 
    var invalidField = $('#formMain').data('formValidation').getInvalidFields().eq(0);

    // get the form-group of that field
    var formGroup = invalidField.parents('.form-group');

    // scroll to it
    if (typeof formGroup !== 'undefined') {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: formGroup.offset().top
        }, 300);
    } else {
        console.log('Nothing to scroll to');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Solution working with the newer Version, which use a event called `core.form.invalid` to trigger the scroll. And `getFields()` to get all Fields an check the parent for `has-error`.

```
var form = $('form');
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    formValidation = FormValidation.formValidation(
        form,
        {
            plugins: {
                autoFocus: new FormValidation.plugins.AutoFocus(),
                declarative: new FormValidation.plugins.Declarative({
                    html5Input: true
                }),
                trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
                submitButton: new FormValidation.plugins.SubmitButton(),
                bootstrap3: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap3()
            }
        }
    ).on('core.form.invalid', function (e) {
        // get all fields
        var fields = formValidation.getFields();
        fields = Object.keys(fields).reverse();

        // get the form-group of that field
        var formGroup;
        $(fields).each(function(index, field) {
            var formGroupCandidate = $('*[name="' + field + '"]').parents('.form-group');
            if (formGroupCandidate.hasClass('has-error')) {
                formGroup = formGroupCandidate;
            }
        });

        // scroll to it
        if (typeof formGroup !== 'undefined') {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: formGroup.offset().top
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

I used your own answer as a basement. So thank you for that!
Hope this will help somebody.